# What to do about this warning email from Google: Publicly accessible Google API key for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-api, google-cloud-functions

As the title states, I've gotten this email for both projects I've made public on Github. One is a landing page for a local business and the other is a CRUD app I have on the App Store; both of which are using Firebase as the backend.

Is the API key being visible on Github such a security risk?
I've done some research after following the instructions in the email to restrict my API and have heard that you cannot make web service requests with a restricted API key.

I just want to show my repos for the projects for the application process and obviously don't want anything bad to happen with them by doing so.

Aren't Firebase APIs meant to be public?
If so, is it just my database rules that need to be stronger/more verbose?

If any more context is needed, please let me know!

Cheers!

**NOTE:** I'm still very new to programming so a lot of this is over my head

Answer (score 6):

For *Firebase* `apiKey` in a web app you are intended to make this key public, so you should ignore this email -- see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/771768